# Issue with test class Assert statement

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public static void UpdateDevAmountAndAmountOppty (List<Opportunity> OptyTriggerNewList, Map<Id,Opportunity> OptyTriggerOldMap, String sOperation) { 


     Set<Id> oppsIds = new Set<Id>();
     List<Opportunity> renewalOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
     List<Opportunity> OppsList = new List<Opportunity>();    
     for( Opportunity opp : OptyTriggerNewList ) {     
            if(sOperation=='sInsert'){
                if(opp.Dev_Amount__c!=null){
                    Opp.Amount = opp.Dev_Amount__c;                    
                }else if(opp.Amount !=null){
                    Opp.Dev_Amount__c = opp.Amount;                    
                }            
            }
            if(sOperation=='sUpdate' && opp.StageName != 'Solicit: Gift Closed/Received 100%'){
                Opportunity oldOpp = OptyTriggerOldMap.get(opp.Id);
                if(opp.Dev_Amount__c <> null && oldOpp.Dev_Amount__c <> opp.Dev_Amount__c && Opp.Amount <> opp.Dev_Amount__c){
                    Opp.Amount = opp.Dev_Amount__c; 
                }else if(opp.Amount <> null && oldOpp.Amount <> opp.Amount && opp.Dev_Amount__c <> Opp.Amount){
                    Opp.Dev_Amount__c = opp.Amount; 
                }            
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Class:

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {              
    Test.startTest();
    Opportunity testopp = new Opportunity();
    testopp.name = 'testOpp';
    testopp.Site__c = 'National';
    testopp.Category__c ='New Opportunity';
    testopp.Cohort__c = 'January 2016';
    testopp.CloseDate = System.today()+10;
    testopp.LeadSource = 'Channel Partners';
    testopp.Stagename = 'Identification: 0%';
    testopp.Restriction_picklist__c = 'Unrestricted';
    testopp.Ask_Amount__c = 200;
    testopp.Amount = 1200;
    testopp.Type = 'Individual';       
    insert testopp;
    //Start test
    system.assertequals(1200,testopp.Dev_Amount__c);      

    Opportunity opp= [select id, Stagename, Amount, Dev_Amount__c from Opportunity where id =:testopp.id ];
    opp.Dev_Amount__c = 1500;
    update opp;
    System.debug('opp.Dev_Amount__c '+opp.Dev_Amount__c);
    system.assertequals(1500,opp.Amount);
    Test.stopTest();

}
```

Trigger:

```
    trigger opportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) { 
/** all events are handled by the opportunityTriggerHandler class */    
if(Trigger.isInsert){
   opportunityTriggerHandler.UpdateDevAmountAndAmountOppty(Trigger.New,Trigger.oldMap, 'sInsert');        
}else
if(Trigger.isUpdate){
   opportunityTriggerHandler.UpdateDevAmountAndAmountOppty(Trigger.New,Trigger.oldMap, 'sUpdate');      
}
```

}

Error:
I am having issue with assert statement.

> 16:48:04.0 (948783585)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException: Assertion
>   Failed: Expected: 1500, Actual: null
>   Class.yearup_opportunityTriggerHandlerTest.myUnitTest: line 21, column
>   1 16:48:04.0 (948790277)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException: Assertion
>   Failed: Expected: 1500, Actual: null
>   Class.yearup_opportunityTriggerHandlerTest.myUnitTest: line 21, column
>   1

Can anyone help me what am I missing?

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: There is no assert in your code that is expecting 400 of anything. Is this the right class?

Comment: @SebastianKessel: There are two asserts in the test class. system.assertequals(1200,testopp.Dev_Amount__c);  and system.assertequals(1500,opp.Amount);

Comment: Your error expects the number 400. It is not coming from that class.

Comment: @SebastianKessel , sorry, I just corrected the error.

Comment: Share your trigger code as well

Comment: @TusharSharma, Hi Tushar, attached the trigger also.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating `opp.Dev_Amount__c = 1500;` but in assert using Amount field

```
system.assertequals(1500,opp.Amount);
```

Change this to

```
system.assertequals(1500,opp.Dev_Amount__c);
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for writing. The reason is I am expecting my trigger to run during the update operation and assign the value to Amount field which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

While that error probably came from another class, I can tell you why you're having problems with the unit test you've posted. Once you've invoked a trigger (e.g. by doing an insert or update), the version of your record in memory no longer matches the data stored in the database. Therefore, you need to make sure you remember to query the data back from the database before you perform your asserts.

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {              
    Test.startTest();
    Opportunity testopp = new Opportunity();
    testopp.name = 'testOpp';
    testopp.Site__c = 'National';
    testopp.Category__c ='New Opportunity';
    testopp.Cohort__c = 'January 2016';
    testopp.CloseDate = System.today()+10;
    testopp.LeadSource = 'Channel Partners';
    testopp.Stagename = 'Identification: 0%';
    testopp.Restriction_picklist__c = 'Unrestricted';
    testopp.Ask_Amount__c = 200;
    testopp.Amount = 1200;
    testopp.Type = 'Individual';       
    insert testopp;
    //Start test
    Opportunity opp= [select id, Stagename, Amount, Dev_Amount__c from Opportunity where id =:testopp.id ];
    system.assertequals(1200,testopp.Dev_Amount__c);      

    opp.Dev_Amount__c = 1500;
    update opp;
    Opportunity opp= [select id, Stagename, Amount, Dev_Amount__c from Opportunity where id =:testopp.id ];
    System.debug('opp.Dev_Amount__c '+opp.Dev_Amount__c);
    system.assertequals(1500,opp.Amount);
    Test.stopTest();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried with that, now this time the assertion is failed in update. any reason?

Comment: @Ajay I'm not sure. What's the value that you actually got?

Comment: actual value I am getting as null